# Waiting for status to be reported - Github Merge Queue

Tags: github, pull-request

The status is reported on the pull request page, but after the pr is added to the Github's Merge Queue product, the status is no longer reported. It is not clear to me how the status could be reported, and this issue seems to be unrelated to the exact products we are waiting for, as you can see in the image that this issue exists with both Coveralls, and CodeQL.

[image: Pull Request stage 1]
[image: Merge Queue stage 2]

Comment: CodeQL status check and Merge Queue are not compatible yet, Github Actions team plans to support it eventually: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/46757#discussioncomment-5365379